# Lua code error (newbie here)

Tags: lua

What's wrong with this piece of code?

```
if key == 'w' then
    if charastate == neutral then 
        charamov = up 
    end
    elseif charastate == lr then
        charastate = neutral then
            charamov = up
    end
end
```

Error is :

> "unexpected symbol near 'then'"

Also it doesn't matter if it's changed for "and"

Thanks, I'm trying to learn by myself but is quite exhausting.

Comment: You should tell what you expect the code to do. Currently no one can tell you exactly how the code should be - just that the error comes from the line `charastate = neutral then` and that there are more than one error in your code. The intention of the code is not clear from the code itself.

Comment: @Rochet2 While not stated explicitly, it is obvious that code inside if should test `charastate` against `neutral/lr` values and then change that state on demand and set `charamov` direction.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you to omit the last `then` because it is not paired off with an `if`.

Indenting the code properly will help you see it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're missing an if statement around here:

```
elseif charastate == lr then
    charastate = neutral then
        charamov = up
end
```

I would also suggest that rather than nesting your `if` statements, use the `and` operator, to make it easier to edit and read your code:

```
if key == 'w' and charastate == neutral then
    charamov = up
elseif key == 'w' and charastate == lr then
    charamov = up
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You are using "then" two times in else if statement.

```
if key == 'w' then
   if charastate == neutral then 
      charamov = up
   elseif charastate == lr then
        charastate = neutral
        charamov = up
   end
end
```

Comment: You can't perform an assignment in the middle of a conditional like that. Assignments in Lua are statements, not expressions.

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry i thought it was equality check. :(

Comment: Also, I'd guess that `charstate` probably can't be both `lr` and `neutral`. So I rather suspect the OP wanted `or` rather than `and`. But then the whole code is spaghetti, so who knows.

Comment: Now i have edited the code. May be this is what Op wanted to do.

Comment: This is still not even balanced, as last `end` is unrelated to anything and indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To help understand what's wrong with original code I commented out corresponding parts, so:

```
if key == 'w' then
    if charastate == neutral then 
        charamov = up 
    --[[ end BAD(1) ]]
    elseif charastate == lr then
        charastate = neutral --[[ then BAD(2) ]]
        charamov = up
    end
end
```

Both troubles are syntactic. 1) `if-elseif` statement has form `if <cond> then <statements> [elseif <statements>]+ end`. Note that there is no `end` before `elseif`. 2) `then` keyword is not applicable. Original code, after proper indenting, looks like this:

```
if key == 'w' then
    if charastate == neutral then 
        charamov = up 
    end
elseif charastate == lr then
    charastate = neutral then -- this is syntax error
    charamov = up
end
end -- this end is excessive, but parser can't even reach here
```

(and barely has any sense for program logic.)